# Tomcat 6.0.x configure HTTP

Tags: java, http-headers, tomcat6

I need to configure the default maxHttpHeaderSize on the HTTP connector and I cant see where to configure it.  I believe it should be under the coyote connector but can only find the catalina attribute in the server.xml.  Can someone edify me where to properly configure this to I can increase the default size of the header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Tomcat 6 docs, http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

You can configure the `maxHttpHeaderSize` within the `HTTP/1.1 <Connector>` already defined within the `Catalina <Service>` in server.xml

Comment: tx.  found that finally and how to configure my ide for it.  for reference jbuilder05 while running edit the server:808x file eliminate the obvious and configure Catalina as desired.  For production it is obvious.  htho

Comment: Thank you, yes that is it, but I found a better solution dwr, strongly recommended